# Java - Checkstyle - Redundant Throws

Tags: java, checkstyle

I'm using STS and installed checkstyle plugin. Using *install new software* with this URL
http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/update.

I have my own checkstyle rule for my Java project. Whenever I change any code and save it shows the following error for me.

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Checkstyle Builder' on project 'myproject'.
cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate RedundantThrows
cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate RedundantThrows
cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate RedundantThrows
cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate RedundantThrows
```

This is my checkstyle rule for RedundantThrows

```
<module name="RedundantThrows">
            <property name="logLoadErrors" value="true" />
            <property name="suppressLoadErrors" value="true" />
        </module>
```

How to fix the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

RedundantThrows was removed with version 6.2 (see https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/473)

Comment: So should I remove that module from checkstyle rule? I recently created a new instance of STS and installed the plugin. Before that it was working perfectly.

Comment: I commented the redundantThrows module. But it is showing the error again.

Comment: Have you tried to run checkstyle from command line? Are you sure only your configuration file is picked up and not any others?

Comment: Hi It was my STS problem. I removed the `redundantThrows` module and then I closed and opened STS. It's working fine now

Comment: It says in the release notes that it was removed without replacements. Any way to get the same check?

http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/#!/releasenotes

Comment: @OliverKuster I've "solved" the problem for now by installing an older release of eclipse-cs.

Comment: @Duncan we stumbled on this problem while updating eclipse and the checkstyle plugin. We have enough legacy software in our development process already...

Comment: For new commers: Goto your checkstyle xml and comment out <module name="RedundantThrows"> tag

Comment: @SurendranDuraisamy I am a "future" reader and I stil have the problem. I have hundreds of [ERROR] MyClass.java[808:1] (whitespace) FileTabCharacter: Line contains a tab character. I have Checkstyle configuration plugin for M2Eclipse 1.0.0.201503101518 com.basistech.m2e.code.quality.checkstyle.feature.f‌​eature.group : Eclipse Checkstyle Plug-in 6.11.1.201510102004 net.sf.eclipsecs.feature.group eclipse-cs.sf.net So what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same with IntelliJ IDEA What I did is I have switched to older version of the checkstyle plugin that can be found here:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065